# Android Search Bar--Results appending

Tags: android, searchbar

I have a search option in my Android application which uses a webservice (when searched for a keyword in a Search Bar) and displays the results on my screen.Immediately, next time, when I search for a different keyword, the result is appended to the first result and displayed.What I want is, to erase/clear the first result and then display the second result and not to Append to the first.Please help as am newbie to Android.

```
public class Srch_Widget extends ListActivity {

ListView lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mysearchscreen);

//In the search box, i will be typing an alphabet and click on "GO button"

goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

//I'm using webservices to retrieve data(JSON String) and will get "EmpName", "EmpID",
"Salary" and the data will be in a single list called "searchlist" that I used below in
ser_listadapter.(if you want I can paste the entire webservices)

ser_listadapter();

}

});
}

public void ser_listadapter() {
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,searchlist,
            R.layout.searchmain, new String[] { "EmpName", "EmpID",
                    "Salary" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.eid, R.id.ename, R.id.sal});

//"searchmain" layout contains 3 textviews with id's: eid,ename,sal

setListAdapter(adapter);
lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Comment: please show us the relevant part of your code, so the answers will be more accurate.

Comment: Code is pasted....please help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clear your searchList in your onClick and before calling your web service:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    searchlist.clear();
    callwebservice(searchlist);
    ser_listadapter();
}
```